# Session data not destroyed after returning to previous page in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to send form data using session to another page in php. But while using 'GO BACK' to return to previous page to resend new session data, it holds the previous session data in input field of second page. I intended to send new session data each time, deleting the previous.

```
session_destroy();
$_SESSION['showvals'] = array();
```

None of this worked.

Here is what I've tried..

page1 - sess1.php

```
<?php 
if (isset($_SESSION['showvals'])) {
 //session_destroy();
 $_SESSION['showvals'] = array();
}
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    $_SESSION['showvals'] = $_POST['sesval'];
}   
 ?>

<strong>Test Form</strong>
<form action="sess2.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="sesval"/>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

page 2- sess2.php

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<strong>Show Form</strong>
<input type="text" name="showval" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['showvals']?>">
<input type="button" name="prevbutton" value="GO BACK" onclick="goback()">
<script type="text/javascript">
        function goback(){
        window.location="sess1.php";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: How do you save the data in the session in sess2.php?

Comment: `session_start();` should be first before any useage of `$_SESSION`

Comment: @Bernhard directly fetching the values from $_SESSION['showvals'] and echoing in input field. Could you please suggest any other alternatives to save the session data?

Comment: So everytime you click go back the $_SESSION['showvals'] will be set to array() and will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check and destroy sessions you need to start the session first

```
if (isset($_SESSION['showvals'])) {
 //session_destroy();
 $_SESSION['showvals'] = array();
}
session_start();
```

Here you are starting the session after checking, so it will never destroy it because is not set

```
//start the session
session_start();
//check
if (isset($_SESSION['showvals'])) {
 //destroy the session
session_destroy();
}
```